# I want to learn about the programming behind audio modification programs

Tags: audio, mac, osx, modification, equalizer

I'm intrigued by the applications like Viper4Android. What language(s) should I know and what concepts? Specifically, I can't seem to find any good audio modification program (or even a good simple equalizer) for osx and I want to find out why and fix that.

Thanks!

Comment: "can't seem to find any good audio modification program [ ] for osx"... you really weren't looking hard enough then - I've got dozens, if not hundreds of plugins, maybe 30 of which are 'simple' EQ shapers.

Comment: I don't get it either!

Answer (score 1):

The keyword for your request is Digital Signal Processing (DSP). That is the science and technology that deals with digitized signals (including audio).

There are several freely available resources on the web to learn some basic or advanced techniques. Nevertheless, some concepts require a solid mathematic background.

Examples (among others) :

[The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm)

[DSP on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/dsp)

[Foundations of Signal Processing](http://www.fourierandwavelets.org/index.php)

You can actually do audio processing with many different languages depending on the context and the required performances. Real-time processing adds a layer of difficulty in terms of programming. If you are interested only in the MacOS platform, the [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework can be used.